# What should we install to include "D3dukmdt.h" in my VC++ code?

Tags: visual-c++, directx, media, direct3d

I want to use D3DDDIFormat enumeration in my code. So I included "D3dukmdt.h" as given in the link "[D3DDDIFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

But when I do # include "D3dukmdt.h"   in my C++ file, I see that the header file D3dukmdt.h is not recognized at all.

Can anyone kindly help me in this. Should I install anything in order to include this header file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need the [Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx) to get access to such things.  It seems unlikely to me that you are trying to write a driver and don't appreciate you need the driver kit so you may be better off explaining what you are trying to do to get a workable alternative explanation